# variance of random variable defined by another variable

Tags: statistics, variance

Let's say I have a random variable $U \sim \operatorname{Uniform}[0,1]$ and I have another random variable $X = \dfrac{4}{1+U^2}$. I want to find the variance of $X$.

So far, I have tried to find the density function of $X$. I found $$f_X(x) = \dfrac{2}{x^2\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-1}}$$ but then I don't know how to find the variance. I know the formula is $\operatorname{var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ but the integral to find $E[X^2]$ looks somewhat hard so I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: You can use $EX^2=\int_0^1 (4/(1+u^2))^2\,du,$ which might be simpler than what you are doing.

Comment: And to find $E[X]$, I can just compute $\int_0^1{4/(1+u^2)}du$ ? Does It work only because $U$ is a uniform variable ?

Comment: I think so. Strictly I guess we should say that $E(X)$ be written as $\int_0^1 4 f(u) / (1 + u^2) \, du$ where $f(u)$ is the density function for $U$ which, in this case is uniform and equal to 1.

Comment: If you're happy with an approximation, then it is possible to use the Taylor series of $X$ as a function of $U$ around the mean $\mu_U$ of $U$ to obtain
$$
E(X)
\approx
g(\mu_U)
+
\frac{1}{2}
\textrm{var}(U)
\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial U^2}
$$
where $g(U)$ is your function.

Comment: Did you introduce the lebesque integral? Because formally $EX^2=\int X^2 dP=\int (4/(1+U^2))^2 dP=\int(4/(1+u^2))^2dP_U(u)$ 
then the Transformation theorem gives you what you need.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

Comment: Forgot to include approximation for variance:

$$
\textrm{var}(X)
\approx
\textrm{var}^2(U)
\left(
\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial U^2}
\right)^2
$$

Comment: @PaulAljabar Thanks for the approximation. For this one I need the exact answer but the formula is good to know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $2\le x\le 4,$
$$
\frac d {dx} \Pr(X\le x) = \frac d {dx} \Pr\left(U \ge \sqrt{\frac 4 x - 1\,} \,\,  \right) = \frac d {dx} \left( 1 - \sqrt{\frac 4 x - 1\,\,} \,\, \right) = \frac{2}{x^2 \sqrt{\frac 4 x - 1}}.
$$
So we agree about the density. But you don't need it:
$$
\operatorname{E}(g(X)) = \int\limits_\text{domain} g(u) f_X(u) \,du.
$$
So
$$
\operatorname{E}\left( \frac 4 {1+U^2} \right) = \int_0^1 \frac 4 {1+u^2} \cdot 1 \,du = 4\arctan 1 - 4\arctan 0 = \pi.
$$
\begin{align}
\text{And } & \operatorname{E}\left( \left( \frac 4 {1+U^2} \right)^2 \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \left( \frac 4 {1+u^2} \right)^2 \cdot 1\,du \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^{\pi/4} (4\cos^2\theta)^2 \big( \sec^2\theta\,d\theta\big) \quad \text{where } u = \tan \theta \\[10pt]
= {} & 16 \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^2\theta\,d\theta = \cdots 
\end{align}

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why the $sec^2 \theta$ disapeared on the last line ?

Comment: I just got it ;) My trig identities were far in my head

Comment: But there's a problem on the last line : the answer for the last integral should be $4 + 2\pi$

Comment: You're right; I was hasty in that very last line.